# Как написать телеграмм бота для получения форм с сайта?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Написал фронт, но никогда не работал с ботами в тг, та и в принципе с ботами. Может кто-то помочь с реализацией. У меня есть форма, есть бот (botFathers) но нету кода для работы бота

Answer (score 1):

Осмелюсь предположить, что вам поможет данный способ.

- Создайте бота, получите токен.
- Создайте обычный чат(чат группу), получите id чата.
- Добавьте бота в чат(чат группу), дайте ему права, запустите.
- Создайте форму на сайте. Думаю вы понимаете как она строится.

```html
     <form class="form" method="post" action="/send.php">
        <div class="form__item">
            <input class="form__input" type="text" name="name" required>
            <label class="form__label">Ваше имя</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__item">
            <input class="form__input" type="text" name="phone" required>
            <label class="form__label">Номер телефона</label>
        </div>
        <input class="form__input btn" type="submit" value="Отправить">
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="order">
    </form>
```

- Далее пишите обработчик в данном случаи send.php

```php
<?php

//В переменную $token нужно вставить токен, который нам прислал @botFather
$token = "1094153697:AAFiLXXXXXLl0hRDsxBij1lddKydKxSSsOg04";

//Сюда вставляем chat_id
$chat_id = "-40XXXX740";

//Определяем переменные для передачи данных из нашей формы
if ($_POST['act'] == 'order') {
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $phone = ($_POST['phone']);

//Собираем в массив то, что будет передаваться боту
    $arr = array(
        'Имя:' => $name,
        'Телефон:' => $phone
    );

//Настраиваем внешний вид сообщения в телеграме
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };

//Передаем данные боту
    $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

//Выводим сообщение об успешной отправке
    if ($sendToTelegram) {
        alert('Спасибо! Ваша заявка принята. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.');
    }

//А здесь сообщение об ошибке при отправке
    else {
        alert('Что-то пошло не так. ПОпробуйте отправить форму ещё раз.');
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пишешь сервер, например на nodejs.. На сервере хранишь токен своего бота. Устанавливаешь необходимые зависимости [npm i node-telegram-bot-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-telegram-bot-api)

```
const http = require('http');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = process.env.TOKEN || "токен бота узнаешь у botFathers"
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
  polling: true,
});
const chatId = process.env.CHATID || "id чата";
//Узнать id чата bot.on('message', function (msg){console.log(msg.from.id)})

http.createServer( (req,res)=>{

if( req.url ==="/message/"){

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",//Внимание к данному заголовку
        "Date": new Date()
    });

    let formData = '';
            
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      formData += chunk.toString();
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      let data = JSON.parse(formData);
      let str = "Категория: " + data.category + "\nИмя: " + data.name+"\nНомер: " + data.num;
      bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str).//бот отправляет сообщение с инфой из формы 
        then(data=>{//Здесь результат успешной отправки сообщения 
          console.log(data)
        }).
        catch(err=>{//Здесь результат ошибки отправки сообщения ботом   
          console.log(err)
        });
    });

    res.end("<div id='request'>Ваша заявка оформлена.</div>");
}else{
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
    res.end(`<h1>Ок</h1>`)
}

}).listen(3000,()=>{console.log("ok")})
```

Форма и обработчик формы, отправляет данные на сервер, принимает ответ с сервера..

```js
let formData = document.forms.communication;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function goSendIt() {
  if (formData.nam.value && formData.num.value) {
    let obj = {
      category: formData.cat.value,
      name: formData.nam.value,
      num: formData.num.value
    }
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xhr.open("POST", "/message/");
    xhr.send(str);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert("Не заполнена")
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="communication">
  <p id="outInfo">Оформить заявку</p>
  <label>Выберите категорию</label>
  <select name="cat">
    <option value="Обратный звонок">Обратный звонок</option>
  </select>
  <label>Ваше имя</label>
  <input name="nam" placeholder="Rudi™" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30">
  <label>Ваш номер телефона</label>
  <input name="num" placeholder="89001234567" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12">
  <input type="button" onclick="goSendIt()" value="Отправить">
</form>
```