# Как сделать отправку форм боту в телеграмм канал?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, tilda

Есть сайт, собранный, боже упаси, на тильде. В нем есть рабочий калькулятор(уже не тильдовский, а написанный на js). По итогу мы имеем на странице блок кальулятора, написанный на js и тильдовский блок, куда клиент должен вписать ФИО и номер телефона. Вопрос: можно ли каким-либо волшебный образом. Можно ли каким-либо образом собрать значения всех форм и отправить в телеграмм канал? Или же необходимо переписать последний блок тильды под код html, оформить его и использовать ajax и php?

Comment: отправлять в любом случае через  бэкенд, а уж где и как вы его напишите - вам виднее

Comment: Можешь [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368321/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0/1368372#1368372) посмотреть для примера...

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у Тильды есть подробная документация по интеграции стороннего ...почти всего. Подробнее можно вот тут посмотреть : [https://help-ru.tilda.cc/tips/javascript...А](https://help-ru.tilda.cc/tips/javascript...%D0%90) вообще у них вполне адекватная поддержка.Ребята реально вникают в проблему в большинстве случаев. Можно калькулятор вообще вынести на отдельную страницу например на WP и там творить что душе угодно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // p.s. а рассказ о ваших личных впечатлениях лучше опубликовать где-нибудь в вашем личном блоге.